# Using merge on many to one/many

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe below, I 'd like to merge them to get ID on df1. However, I find by using merge, I cannot get the ID if the names are more than one. df2 has unique name, df1 and df2 are different in rows and columns. My code below:

df1:

```
   Name Region
0  P    Asia
1  Q    Eur
2  R    Africa
3  S    NA
4  R    Africa
5  R    Africa
6  S    NA
```

df2:

```
   Name  Id
0  P     1234
1  Q     1244
2  R     1233
```

code:

```
x= df1.assign(temp1 = df1.groupby ('Name').cumcount())
y= df2.assign(temp1 = df2.groupby ('Name').cumcount())
xy= x.merge(y, on=['Name',temp2],how = 'left').drop(columns = ['temp1'])
```

The output of xy isbelow, how to find Id for those NAN?

```
   Name Region Id
0  P    Asia   1234
1  Q    Eur    1244
2  R    Africa NAN
3  S    NA     NAN
4  R    Africa NAN
5  R    Africa NAN
6  S    NA     NAN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you cannot use pandas merge?

```
name_list = ['P','Q','R','S','R','R','S']
country_list = ['Asia','Eur','Africa','NA','Africa','Africa','NA']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name_list,'Region':country_list})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['P','Q','R'],'Id':[1234,1244,1233]})

result = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Name',how='left')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Region      Id
0    P    Asia  1234.0
1    Q     Eur  1244.0
2    R  Africa  1233.0
3    S      NA     NaN
4    R  Africa  1233.0
5    R  Africa  1233.0
6    S      NA     NaN
```

Comment: I cannot get the same number of rows on df1 when doing a left join on Name. That's why I add a cumcount function and a temp column.

Comment: @Jennie Are you getting a higher number of rows? That might be caused by there not being a 1-1 relationship between Name and Id in df2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your syntax is off on `temp2`. First of all, you forgot quotes. Second, it should be `'temp1'` instead of `temp2`.
2. You merged on two columns. If you only merged on `Id`, then you wouldn't have `NaN` values. However, since you merged on `temp1`, there was some data that didn't match across the dataframes. There is no `S` value in the `Name` column in the second dataframe, so you would expect `NaN` for the `S` values after merging.
3. If your goal is to now fill those `NaN` values but with a different methodology, then you can do that. IS that what you want to do, now just merge on `Id` instead of `Id` and `temp1`. Is this what you mean?

---

```
x= df1.assign(temp1 = df1.groupby ('Name').cumcount())
y= df2.assign(temp1 = df2.groupby ('Name').cumcount())
xy= x.merge(y, on=['Name','temp1'],how='left').drop('temp1')
xy
Out[1]: 
  Name  Region        Id
0    P    Asia    1234.0
1    Q     Eur    1244.0
2    R  Africa    1233.0
3    S     NaN       NaN
4    R  Africa       NaN
5    R  Africa       NaN
6    S     NaN       NaN
```

Comment: There is actually S in df2 but I forget to type in... temp2 is a mistype, so #1 & #2 are no longer issues. The reason I use cumcount() nd add a temp column is that merge wouldn't give me same numbers of rows on df1 for a left join. But I find using this methodology, duplicate names like R would find ID in the list for just once, you can see index #4 #5 in the output has no ID.

Comment: @jennie in addition to the output, please include expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you merge on `cumcount()`? that way, you only merge them one-to one. Just merge:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='outer')
```

Output:

```
  Name  Region      Id
0    P    Asia  1234.0
1    Q     Eur  1244.0
2    R  Africa  1233.0
3    R  Africa  1233.0
4    R  Africa  1233.0
5    S     NaN     NaN
6    S     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: using just merge would retun more rows on df1 which is not what I am seeking for